# Ошибка компиляции с extends App

Tags: классы, вывод, компилятор, scala

Приведённый ниже код работает нормально(сортирует массив):

[image: Код без ошибки]

Но если после "object Майн" добавить "extends App", код выдаёт ошибку, почему?

[image: код с ошибкой]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Трейт `App` сам определяет метод `main`, для этих целей и существует. Переопределять метод не нужно, да и нельзя.

```
object Main extends App {
  val temp = Array(10, 120, 4, 12, 41, 4, 78, 8)
  temp.sorted foreach println
}
```

```
4
4
8
10
12
41
78
120
```